# Text over image in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

Hi guys I am learning sketch and in the tutorial Im watching the guy place the text box over the video image in the background, but when I'm following his instructions my text box is going behind the image.

Can anyone please help?

Cheers

[image: Screen shot sketch]

Comment: Take a look at this Sketch Talk [page](https://sketchtalk.io/discussion/1066/is-their-a-way-to-bring-a-layer-to-top-of-an-artboard-without-dragging-it-i-see-no-shortcut)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Your text is on a layer under the video layer. Move it above the video layer. Familiarise yourself with the [basic concept of layers](https://www.sketch.com/docs/layer-basics/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Exchange!

You have multiple options to move a layer (some text, for example) upward or backward.

In your example, the text is simply **behind** the *video* group. That shows up in your artboard listing (left panel) because the first element is on top of your artboard (and the last one is on the bottom).

I captured two ways to move a layer on Sketch :

1. Right-click the layer you want to move and select **Move Upward** (or Move Backward you want to put it behind something else)
2. Select your layer in the left panel and drag and drop it wherever you want in your list.

[image: image description]

(A better quality gif can be viewed here: https://giant.gfycat.com/WelldocumentedFrenchGnatcatcher.webm)

A third option is to do it thanks to a keyboard shortcut : Select the layer you want to move (either by clicking on it in the artboard or from the left panel) and press :

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> to move the layer **upward**

<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> to move the layer **backward**

Also, as @billy-kerr pointed, you can have a look at this [official documentation](https://www.sketch.com/docs/layer-basics/) talking about layers.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the col-1 folder and drop it over the video folder.
the sketch follows top to down priority rule to represent elements. so if you put your text folder above the video folder, it seems the text is in front of the video.